# How can I use webform to upload assets and create a project that can be assigned to different users

Tags: rules, webforms, distributions

I am trying to put together a creative request form that a client would fill out. A studio manager would then follow up and assign to a project manager. I am using webform and rules as a starting point with the possibility of using Open Atrium.

Answer (score 0):

if you want client submissions to become content I recommend [EntityForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) Then you could use for example the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module to assure the content is moderated by a *manager* into approval.

You likely want your content type to show limited items to the client and then more options to the manager. I would try to do this with the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

Lastly you could automate sending emails and stuff on some events if you want using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).